# MySQL Count and sum based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to count SN for each PN and sum it based on a condition (in below case Loc)?

```
create table table1 (
            code int(10) primary key,
            PN varchar(10) not null,
        SN varchar(10) not null,
                Loc varchar(10));

insert into table1 values (1,'T1','a1','a');
insert into table1 values (2,'T1','a2','a');
insert into table1 values (3,'T1','a3','a');
insert into table1 values (4,'T1','a4','b');
insert into table1 values (5,'T1','a5','b');
insert into table1 values (6,'T1','a6','b');
insert into table1 values (7,'T2','a1','a');
insert into table1 values (8,'T2','a2','a');
insert into table1 values (9,'T2','a3','a');
insert into table1 values (10,'T2','a4','b');
insert into table1 values (11,'T2','a5','b');
insert into table1 values (12,'T2','a6','b');
insert into table1 values (13,'T2','a7','b');
```

The results I try to achieve is:

```
PN  a   b
T1  3   3
T2  3   4
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just conditional aggregation:

```
select pn, sum(loc = 'a') as a, sum(loc = 'b') as b
from table1
group by pn;
```

If you have an unknown list of `loc` values, then you might need a dynamic query.  Google "MySQL dynamic pivot".

Answer (score 1):

You can use *conditional* aggregation :

```
select PN, sum(case when Loc = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as a,
           sum(case when Loc = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) as b
from table1 t1
group by PN;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this one

```
select PN, count(case when Loc = 'a' then 1 else null end) a,  count(case when Loc = 'b' then 1 else null end) b
from table1
group by PN
```

Comment: Thanks All. It works like magic in mysql where I have just one table however in my real example where I have 3 joined tables it produces combination for all records. So, instead 2 I get +100,000 with zeros. Any idea for the reason? I add all columns to group by and end up with 1 for the location when PN is present. How can I sum up (one is achived by `(CASE WHEN loc = 'A'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'A'`

Comment: Can you get sample with real tables @Kalenji

Comment: please post sql query you run on real example @Kalenji