# count and sum some column based on other colomns

Tags: mysql

count and sum some sql cols based on other cols

hi. i have sql table like this

```
ftozi| mvfeeder | blackouts
f1   |m1        | 1
f1   |m1        | 2
f1   |m2        | 1
f2   |m1        | 1
f2   |m3        | 1
f2   |m1        | 3
```

i want to get output like this

```
ftozi |mvfeeder |numOfblackouts | sumofblackouts
f1    | m1      |2              |3
f1    | m2      |1              |1
f2    | m1      |2              |4
f2    | m3      |1              |1
```

i see this post [MySQL Count and sum based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361125/mysql-count-and-sum-based-on-condition)
but it needs to be write fore every mvfeeder. this is the simple table. i have very big table with multiplt ftozi col that contain multiple mvfeeder. it is possible that mvfeeder value is similar between ftozi but i want to count mvfeeder and sum its blackouts based on ftozie

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i could not figur it out how to do it. the simple cod is select `mvFeeder`, count(`mvFeeder`) from faults_mv group by mvFeeder. but it count similare mvfeeders in different ftozi that i dont want to. and also i dont want to use some condition like where ftozi=f1 because there is many ftozie and mvfeeder. i want count mvfeeder  based on ftozi and sum its blackouts based on ftozi and mvfeeder

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to get count and sum of blackouts with group by on ftozi and mvfeeder. Try something like this:

```
SELECT FTOZI, MVFEEDER, COUNT(BLACKOUTS) numOfBlackouts, SUM(BLACKOUTS) sumOfBlackouts FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY FTOZI, MVFEEDER;
```

Comment: thanks. it worked fine with sum fixes. i wanted to count mvfeeder and sum blackout.i didn't know that kind of grouping multiple cols. its fine. but how far it can goes. i mean how many cols can be grouped and is it important to write the name of cols with order that we want to grouping first?

Comment: Order of columns does not matter in group by clause. As for number of columns, I suggest you look at the docs.